# vending machine code. how to calculate change?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a program for a vending machine. The program will ask the user to pick an option and it will calculate the change depending on the amount entered and the price of the product.

I can't get the program to calculate the change. I tried this but it doesn't work

```
 Select Case choice
            Case "1"
                Console.WriteLine("enter amount")
                amount = Console.ReadLine()
                If amount < 0.6 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("not enough")
                Else
                    change = amount - 0.6
                  
                End If
```

full code

```
   Dim choice As String
    Dim amount As Integer
    Dim change As Integer


    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("option 1: snickers price = 60p")
        Console.WriteLine("option 2: coke price = £1")
        Console.WriteLine("option 3")
        Console.WriteLine("option 3")
        Console.WriteLine("option 4")
        Console.WriteLine("option 5")
        Console.WriteLine("option 6")
        Console.WriteLine("option 7")
        Console.WriteLine("option 8")
        Console.WriteLine("option 9")
        Console.WriteLine("option 10")
        choice = Console.ReadLine()
        Select Case choice
            Case "1"
                Console.WriteLine("enter amount")
                amount = Console.ReadLine()
                If amount < 0.6 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("not enough")
                Else
                    change = amount - 0.6
                   
                End If


            Case "2"
                Console.WriteLine("enter amount")
                amount = Console.ReadLine()
                If amount < 1 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("not enough")
                Else
                    change = amount - 1
                End If
        End Select
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Calculating change is a very common homework question and there would be examples all over the web. The principle is simple: integer division and remainder. You perform integer division with the largest denomination and then get the remainder, then repeat with ever smaller denominations. There's nothing even close to that in your code so you should start with that logic, try some manual calculations, develop an algorithm and then write code to implement that logic. If you can't explain the specific logic you're trying to implement then you shouldn't even be trying to write code.

Comment: Can't I get the program to calculate the change by taking away the price from the amount the user enters @jmcilhinney

Comment: If all you want is the amount of change then yes, it's just a subtraction, but I'm not sure why you would need our help to subtract one number from another. I assumed that you were asking how to calculate the makeup of the change, e.g. if the change was $1.85 in the US then that would be 1x$1 + 3x25c + 1x10c. That is what I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in your code:

- You are using Integer type for data that is decimal, so first of all you need to change the first two variables to `Double`
- You are never showing the value that `Change` has; you calculate it but it is never shown on the screen. I have added a line that shows the change only if it is greater than 0.

Try something similar to the code I show below and see if you can continue from there:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim choice As String
    Dim amount As Double
    Dim change As Double
    
    Console.WriteLine("option 1: snickers price = 60p")
    Console.WriteLine("option 2: coke price = £1")
    Console.WriteLine("option 3")
    Console.WriteLine("option 3")
    Console.WriteLine("option 4")
    Console.WriteLine("option 5")
    Console.WriteLine("option 6")
    Console.WriteLine("option 7")
    Console.WriteLine("option 8")
    Console.WriteLine("option 9")
    Console.WriteLine("option 10")
    choice = Console.ReadLine()

    Select Case choice
       Case "1"
          Console.WriteLine("enter amount")
          amount = Console.ReadLine()
          If amount < 0.6 Then
             Console.WriteLine("not enough")    
          Else
             change = amount - 0.6      
          End If 

          Case "2"
             Console.WriteLine("enter amount")
             amount = Console.ReadLine()
             If amount < 1 Then
                Console.WriteLine("not enough")
             Else
                 change = amount - 1
             End If
        End Select

        If change > 0 then
           Console.WriteLine("Change: " & change)
        End If
    End Sub
```